# Connecting to a DB using PDO returning a non object error

Tags: php, object, pdo, fetch, sqlconnection

I tried following this tutorial on PDOs, followed it exactly, yet when trying to connect on a very basic level, it's outputing a non object error. I made a small test to determining the boolean of the $query variable and it's coming out as false which is generating the error. Why is it doing this?:

**TUTORIAL**

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lb0NYODtGr4&feature=share&list=EC23A4AFEA46A5CB23

**ERROR**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\dentaloffice\php\php_connect.php on line 16

**CODE**

```
<?php

$config['db'] = array(
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'dbname'    => 'dentaloffice'
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname =' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);

$query = $db->query("SELECT appointments.ROOM FROM appointments");

if($query === false){
    echo '$query variable returned false <br>';
}else{
    echo '$query variable returned true <br>';
}

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['ROOM'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Please add `print_r($db->errorInfo());` line to the `false` branch. What does it show?

Comment: Also if your wanting to print variables you need to use double quotes not single ones

Comment: Hi, @raina77ow, this is what it returned: `Array ( [0] => 3D000 [1] => 1046 [2] => No database selected )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname =' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
```

... into this ...

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$config['db']['host']};dbname={$config['db']['dbname']}",
              $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
```

In other words, remove the whitespace symbol right after `dbname`, and it will work. ) PDO DSN syntax is quite strict, and the string in your example is parsed like no database was specified - hence an error you see.

BTW, it's a good practice to always check `errorInfo()` in the way shown in my previous comment in `false query/statement/result` branches of the PDO code. And now you probably see why. )

Comment: Oh, wow! That worked. I would've never guessed that was the issue. I possibly even placed that whitespace to make it look cleaner, I guess. 
Thank you a lot, @raina77ow!

Answer (score 1):

Create a phpinfo file and check you have PDO enabled and have correct drivers installed.

Comment: Solved it :P It was a really retarded mistake. I was using a tablename instead of the actual DB name. My great bad. Thank you greatly!

Comment: If PDO were not enabled, the error would be totally different (and in another place).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure u have PDO enabled.

btw you could just check for the query validation like this:

```
if($query) // will return true if succefull else it will return false 
{ 
// code here for true
}
```